# Prove that $S_n=⟨(12),(23),...,((n-1)n)⟩$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

Assume we know that $S_n=⟨(12),(13),...,(1n)⟩$, then prove $S_n=⟨(12),(23),...,((n-1)n)⟩$

I didn't understand this proof below:

For $i=2$ at $(1 \ i)$ so $(1 \ i) \in S_n$, then assuming that $(1 \ i)$ for all $i\in\{1,...,n\}$ we have

$(1 \ i+1)=(1 \ i)(i \ i+1)(1 \ i)$ then $(1 \ i+1) \in S_n$ so $(1 \ i) \in S_n$ really hold.

What I didn't get:

- Why does this factorization imply to $(1 \ i+1)\in S_n$?
- If the reason for that is $(1 \ i) \in S_n, (i \ i+1) \in S_n$ implies to the "product" belonging to $S_n$, then why would I not just write $(1 \ i+1)=(1 \ i)(i \ i+1)$?

Comment: What is your source of the question?  What is your source of the proof?

Comment: a pdf from my tutor but it's in portuguese

Comment: It should not say "assuming $(1,i)$ for all $i \in \{1,2,\cdots n\}.$ First of all one should say assuming *something* about $(1,i).$ Second if it said "assuming $(1,i) \in S_n$ for all those $i$" then it would be assuming all that is supposed to be shown.

Comment: If you try e.g. $(1,4)(4,5)$ you get that indeed 1 goes to 5, hower 5 goes to 4 not 1 so you don't get $(1,5)$ as the product. You need all three transpositions. In this case you need $(14)(45)(14)$ which does come out just $(1,5)$ [the 4 ends up back to 4 so doesn't move]

Answer (score 2):

$⟨(12),(23),...,((n-1)n)⟩$ means all elements which are generated by the product of some terms of $(12),(23),...,$ and $((n-1)n)$.

Now $(13)=(12)(23)(12)$ so $(13)$ is an element of $⟨(12),(23),...,((n-1)n)⟩$ and we can consider $(13)$ as one of the generators.

Now $(14)=(13)(34)(13)$ so $(14)$ is an element of $⟨(12),(23),...,((n-1)n)⟩$ and we can consider $(14)$ as one of the generators.

We can continue this by induction, and, with the knowledge of $(1\ i) \in⟨(12),(23),...,((n-1)n)⟩$, we realize $(1\ i+1)=(1\ i)(i\ i+1)(1\ i) \in ⟨(12),(23),...,((n-1)n)⟩$

Finally, since  $(1\ i) \in ⟨(12),(23),...,((n-1)n)⟩$ for all $i$ and $S_n=⟨(12),(13),...,(1n)⟩$, then $S_n=⟨(12),(23),...,((n-1)n)⟩$.

Comment: I didn't realize this at all I was just get confused $⟨$ as $\{$. but what has this product got three terms ?

Comment: I do not understand your question. It does not matter why there are three terms or five or whatever; it only matters that you can generate $(1\ i)$ by the product of elements in the form $(i\ i+1)$. For example, $(14)=(13)(34)(13)=(12)(23)(12)(34)(12)(23)(12)$